# Why does $\int_1^\infty\frac1xdx=\infty$ but $\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}dx=1$ when their graphs are the same shape?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, graphing-functions

Why is it that $$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx = \infty,$$ but$$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx = 1,$$ when their graphs are the same shape?

They are basically the same shape. Even if $\frac{1}{x^2}$ approaches zero faster than $\frac{1}{x}$, that should not matter, right?

Comment: The fact that $\frac{1}{x^2}$ approaches $0$ faster than $\frac1x$ is the single most important thing about this problem. Why do you think it doesn't matter?

Comment: *"even if $1/x^2$ approaches zero faster than $1/x$, that should not matter, right?"* ... Given the dramatic differences in their integrals, it *does* matter a great deal.

Comment: Can you explain why it matters then?

Comment: It matters because it is significant enough to make one of the integrals finite and the other infinite. Which is true because $1/x^2$ does approach zero faster than $1/x$. Which is significant because the first sentence. Significance is a recursive argument here

Comment: By calculating the indefinite integral, you should be able to see the answer to your question quite quickly. This is definitely a problem where the answer is unintuitive, but nevertheless correct. When you study convergence of series, which is what this question entails, you'll definitely come to learn that the rate of decrease of a function *absolutely* matters. For instance, the sum of all numbers equal to $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ converges, while the sum of all numbers equal to $\frac{1}{2^n}$ converges to 1. However, no one has the time to deliver a lecture. Keep up your studies.

Comment: The functions $f(x)=\frac ax$ are special because the area of an $x \times f(x)$ rectangle is independent of $x$

Comment: They don't have the same basic shape because their curvature is different. By that logic $x^2$, $x^4$, and $\cosh x$ are all the same shape, too (which is not true).

Comment: Saying that $\frac1x$ and $\frac1{x^2}$ have the same shape is like saying that $|x|$ and $x^2$ have the same shape.

Answer (score 3):

I think some calculations can be useful in understanding how $f(x) = 1/x$ and $g(x) = 1/x^2$ are different.

If I choose $x = 10$, then $f(10) = 0.1$ but $g(10) = 0.01$.  For $f(x)$ to equal $0.01$, we would need to choose $x = 100$, but at this $x$-value, $g(100) = 0.0001$.  And for $f(x)$ to equal $0.0001$, we'd need to choose $x = 10000$, but $g(10000) = 0.00000001$.

In general, for a given fixed $x > 1$, $g(x)$ is $x$ times smaller than the corresponding $f(x)$.  So if $x = 10^6$,  $g$ is already a *million* times smaller than $f$ at that value.  The extent to which $g$ is smaller than $f$ is exactly proportional to the value of $x$, so the farther out along the positive $x$-axis you go, the more dramatic the ratio of $g$ to $f$.

There are other more familiar pairs of functions that also behave in this way.  For instance, compare $f(x) = x$ to $g(x) = x^2$.  Here, $g$ is $x$ times *larger* than $f$, and a quick sketch of the graphs of $f$ and $g$ show just how dramatically differently these behave.  Moreover, you can observe that $x$ and $x^2$ are the reciprocals of $1/x$ and $1/x^2$--so if you remark how much more rapidly $x^2$ grows compared to $x$, you must also see that $1/x^2$ decreases that much more rapidly to $0$ compared to $1/x$.

Answer (score 1):

They may look similar on $[1,\infty)$, but with a change of perspective they look rather different. Let $z=1/x$, or $x=1/z$. Then $dx=-1/z^2$ and the limits of integration become $1\mapsto 1$ and $+\infty\mapsto 0^+$, or just $0$. Then
$$
\int_1^{\infty} x^{-2}\,dx = \int _{1}^{0}(-dz) = \int _0^1 \,dz = 1 
$$So, under this substitution, the new integrand is a *constant* and the range of integration is $[0,1]$: this is well-behaved. But the other one looks very different:
$$
\int _1^{\infty} x^{-1}\,dx = \int_{1}^{0} z^{-1}(-dz ) = \int _0^1 z^{-1}\,dz
$$Post-transformation, the integrand *still has a singularity* (of course, a priori it could still be improperly integrable, but...) and the FTC shows that the value of the integral is unbounded:
$$
=\left. \ln(z)\right|_0^1 = \ln(1)-\ln(0) = -(-\infty)=\infty
$$Strictly speaking, I should be taking the lower limit as $a\to 0+$ for some positive $a$, but you get the idea.